# Link to open web app version of a document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, office-web-apps

I am trying to email out the URL of a document through a SharePoint workflow. However, the link that is sent tries to download the document rather than open it with the Word App. When I look at the share link in the document library it is different from the one that the workflow is giving me. Is there a way to generate this url from a workflow?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `?web=1` to any document link in SharePoint and it will try to open it in the navigator,

Hope this helps!